# Iterate an array and calculate string numbers

Tags: reactjs

So I have an array of objects that I want to iterate and calculate the values in it and then assing it to the total variable in a React state.

Here for example is the state:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
    total: '',
    items: [
    {
     name: 'Ketchup',
     price: '100'
     },
     // 100 more items like this for example
    ]
})
```

So what I want to do is calculate all items price and assign to variable total, and the issue is that the price property is string and not a number.

Comment: `setState(prev => ({...prev, total: (prev.items.map(x => parseInt(x.price))).reduce((t, i) => (t + i), 0)}));` <-- please share feedback if this works. If `price` may be decimals (like `100.75`), then instead of `parseInt` try `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var myData = [

    {
        "name": "Ketchup",
        "price": "100"
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": "150"
    },
    {
        "name": "Orange",
        "price": "800"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mango",
        "price": "1000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Milk",
        "price": "250"
    }
]

let total = 0

for(let i = 0 ; i< myData.length ; i++){
    total = +myData[i].price + total
}


console.log(total)
```

```js
var myData = [

    {
        "name": "Ketchup",
        "price": "100"
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": "150"
    },
    {
        "name": "Orange",
        "price": "800"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mango",
        "price": "1000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Milk",
        "price": "250"
    }
]

let total = 0

for(let i = 0 ; i< myData.length ; i++){
    total = +myData[i].price + total
}


console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your state seems to be big, so please use lazy initialization

```
const getInitialState = () => ({
    total: '',
    items: [
    {
     name: 'Ketchup',
     price: '100'
     },
     // 100 more items like this for example
    ]
})

const [state, setState] = useState(getInitialState)
```

Although it is possible to convert all price's string to number in the `getInitialState` I assume you are going to get all that object somehow from props and don't want to change that in the first place and once

```
const totalPrice = state.items.reduce((acc, item) => +item.price + acc,0)
```

> **NOTE**: string + number, number + string cause string
> **NOTE**: +string will cast the string to number if it is possible

In case you want to prevent extra re-calculation

```
const totalPrice = useMemo(() => {
  return state.items.reduce((acc, item) => +item.price + acc,0)
}, [state.items])
```

you can then setState the total inside some effect with the same deps, but for separation (you can skip saving something which can be derived from the `items`, also you can add another state for `total` only, which seems more reactive and performant